# As a GM, how can I create and role-play diverse NPCs better?

Tags: gm-techniques, roleplaying, new-gm

I am new to GMing (and role-playing in general, for that matter) and I am having a somewhat difficult time making plausible and interesting NPCs. This is especially true with NPCs who are not "typical adults", such as a child or an NPC who is unlike me. Most of the time, the interaction with the PCs turns into, "Ask me questions...uh...here is a quest...uh...boring stereotype...uh...".

So, what is the best way to make interacting with these kinds of NPCs both more realistic and engaging? Ideally, I want to turn NPCs from "I'm here for plot reasons" into engaging, memorable and realistic characters,

Comment: This seems to be two questions.  "creating" is a probably duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/how-can-a-gm-quickly-create-interesting-engaging-characters and "role-playing" is related/possible duplicate of: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/what-is-a-good-way-to-become-a-better-npc-monster-actor - I suggest closing this one and chiming in on those two. But as usual, I await a couple community close votes before I step in and mod-close, as I am a benevolent nature spirit.